# Bootstrap navbar stopped working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a website built from a template using bootstrap.min.css for the navbar, it was functioning perfectly a few days ago and has suddenly stopped working only in Chrome desktop. It functions fine on Chrome mobile and all other desktop browsers. Does anyone know if Google changed code that I need to adjust for? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: If you are using CDN for JS/CSS then this might be a reason. Some of JS/CSS file on CDN might have been changed and your existing code might have stopped working.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm not using cdn. I have locally saved files for version 3.1.1. I've found another website that has the same issue http://www.lexusls.asia/ though it's from a design site so I don't know how valid it is.

Comment: I have discovered that it is the scrolling script that is preventing it from being active, when I remove it the navigation jumps to the section IDs as expected. Is this script no longer correct for Chrome but still will function in other browsers?

 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";
  $('#main-menu #headernavigation').onePageNav({
   currentClass: 'active',
   changeHash: false,
   scrollSpeed: 750,
   scrollThreshold: 0.5,
   scrollOffset: 60,
   filter: '',
   easing: 'swing'
  });  
 });